# NVMe M.2 SSD keeps disappering every now and then whenever PC reboots

Tags: windows-10, powershell, dropbox, m.2, samsung-ssd

I have HP Z2 SFF G4 Workstation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz  3.19 GHz with Windows 10 Pro 21H2. I have installed dropbox on NVME samsung SSd 970 SCSI 2GB and manually assigned it drive letter `Z:` and volume label `DropBox`. Now whenever I start my PC in the morning I get message from dropbox that `Drive Z:` is missing.
I then have to again reassign drive letter Z to that volume and reboot my PC. This problem occurs randomly in 1-2 days interval. I even changed NVME SSD and even changed the slot of this SSD in my PC but the problem still ocuurs every now and then. I have other drive like 850Evo as secondary drive and samsung 980 pro as my boot drive and I never faced this issue with 850Evo as secondary drive when Dropbox was installed on 850Evo. I checked drive with samsung magician and it says drive is good.

Is there any thing I can do to trubleshoot this issue to find if this is a issue with Dropbox or Windows?. Can I have some powershell script or batch file that I can execute on my PC startup to check if `Driveletter Z:` is missing for volume named `Dropbox` and assign it before other software like Dropbox and Snagit use them?

Comment: Check the HR website to ensure there is not a BIOS firmware update that is available, and if so, update it. I would then update all firmware drivers too and see if that helps. Another thought is to assign the SSD another drive letter than "Z" and see if it also has the same issue. Have you check the event viewer system and app logs to see if it screams when it is an issue and compare there when it works and doesn't work. I've had issues similar with a Dell machine though and hoping the updates most recently helps but that was more like every so many months rather than days.

Comment: Thank you @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle. I updated BIOS using HP Support Assistant and even checked Event Viewer where I always found two errors related to dropbox as below 

Application Logs (Error)
dbxsvc error: CertFindCertificateInStore failed with: (-2146885628) Cannot find object or property.
dbxsvc error: Failed to get driver message: (-2147024890) The handle is invalid.

Comment: Check to see if there is an n Intel Rapid Storage Technology
(Intel RST) driver too. Check over specs here and compare with what you have too https://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/getpdf.aspx/c05987487.pdf. Do a keybiard Ctrl+F then search for nvme for quick finds. Maybe something there will scream out to you that's obvious. Maybe unseat and reseat the nvme drive on the motherboard too. To dropbox error is likely related to the drive not being accessible to the OS and it cannot find a mount point, etc.